# Trouble understanding why this sentence went to Dative

Tags: article, declension

Here is a quote from Siddhartha from which I am having a little trouble understanding the declension of the article in bold:

*"Im Schatten des Hauses, in der Sonne des Flußufers bei den Booten, im Schatten des Salwaldes, im Schatten des Feigenbaumes wuchs Siddahartha auf, der schöne Sohn des Brahmanen, der junge Falke, zusammen mit Govinda, seinem Freunde, **dem** Brahmanensohn"*.

I'm looking for an explanation on why *dem Brahmanensohn* is Dative here, couldn't understand it for myself.

Am I right in assuming the translation for this last part is as follows:

"...the beautiful son of the Brahmins, the young Falcon, together with Govinda, girlfriend of his, the son of the Brahmins."?

It feels that should be nominative but I'm just beginning with grammar so there is probably something basic I'm missing here.

Comment: There is no girlfriend. "Govinda, seinem Freunde, dem Brahmanensohn" is one single person and a male friend. And Siddahartha "wuchs mit ihm auf", "ihm" referring to that friend.

Comment: Oh, ok, I forgot female friend was Freundin. Thanks a lot. Govinda sounded too much of a female name to my ears.

Comment: I think I get it. So "dem Brahmanensohn" is referring to Govinda, and not Siddhartha?

Comment: "So "dem Brahmanensohn" is referring to Govinda, and not Siddhartha?" Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that part simplifies to

> ... zusammen mit dem Brahmanensohn ...

(*Govinda*, and *seinem Freunde* is simply a list of additional denominations for the same person)

And **mit** is a preposition that takes the dative.

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble visualizing that because of the ordering of the phrases.

Comment: The ordering is for creating a climax. The last item gets most attention.

Answer (score 3):

> mit Govinda, seinem Freunde, dem Brahmanensohn

*mit* requires Dativ case. *Govinda*, *seinem Freunde*, *dem Brahmanensohn* are all in Dativ.

*seinem Freunde* is easily recognizable as an apposition. Somewhat surprisingly this sentence has a second one with *dem Brahmanensohn*. That's fairly uncommon in ordinary German. You find it relatively often in religious texts
(e.g., *Dem Messias, dem Gesandten Gottes, dem Erlöser, dem Gottessohn jubelten sie zu.*). Hesse adopted this style conscientiously, when he wrote Siddharta.